Manga which involved knights, the Catholic Church, and people with powers
I read this manga years ago (10 years or so) and I don't remember much, but I hope to find it.
I remember it had knights; the church was involved too, so I suppose it takes place during the medieval period. Certain people had powers and one that I remember particularly was a girl (I believe) who could either melt people's skin or give the illusion that she had melted their skin like candle. One other character used a cross that looks like an anchor cross to fight. I believe their name was François Xavier or François d’Assise or another catholic saint's name. A bunch of character also had catholic saints' names.
I only read one tome so I barely remember the story itself. Does anyone remember this manga?

Not sure about Francois or the melted skin, but church reminds me of "A Certain Magical Index" - https://toarumajutsunoindex.fandom.com/wiki/Toaru_Majutsu_no_Index_Wiki, where https://toarumajutsunoindex.fandom.com/wiki/Roman_Catholic_Church (and other churches) plays a significant role.
